# Flex: pass a parameter to itemEditor

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a datagrid where one column calls a custom an itemEditor like;

```
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="city"
                                       width="150" 
                                       headerText="City" 
                                       itemEditor="components.ComboCity" 
                                       editorDataField="city"/>
```

And my custom itemEditor looks like;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                              xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                              xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                              focusEnabled="true">
        <mx:ComboBox id="comboBox"/>
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                public var myString:String;
                .
                .
                .
```

How can I pass from my main application a value to `myString` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this link, I think you will find your answer there :

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_3.html

Furher xp:

```
  myGrid.editedItemRenderer.data.City=myEditor(myGrid.itemEditorInstance).setCity.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

**The best solution for me:**

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.events.DataGridEvent;

        private function itemEditorCreateHandle(event:DataGridEvent):void
        {               
            ComboCity(DataGrid(event.target).itemEditorInstance).myString = "Put here the value";
        }   

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:DataGridColumn      
    dataField="city"
    width="150" 
    headerText="City" 
    itemEditor="components.ComboCity" 
    itemEditorCreate="itemEditorCreateHandle(event);" 
    editorDataField="city"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always refer to parent component from itemRenderer by calling "outerDocument" property, e.g:

```
myString = outerDocument.componentProperty
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_6.html